# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth') on vuetify3 slider group component

Tags: vuetifyjs3

I'm using vuetify3 for my front application. I want to have a slider with small picture that permit to select images like that :

[image]

the code doing it well but when i click on one of a small picture, an error appears :

```
helpers.mjs:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientWidth')
    at calculateCenteredOffset (helpers.mjs:36:1)
    at eval (VSlideGroup.mjs:102:1).
```

this is the code of the slider concerned :

```html
<v-slide-group show-arrows center-active mandatory class="background-white justify-center">
        <v-row justify="center" align="center" >
          <v-slide-group-item v-for="productVariant in productCard.variantsFiltered" :key="productVariant"  v-slot="{ isSelected, toggle }">
            <v-card :class="['ma-3', selectedClass]" height="52" width="50" @click="toggle">
              <div class="flex-column fill-height align-center ">
                <div class="cover">
                  <v-img height="50" rounded @click="changeSrc(productVariant)"
                  :src="productVariant.imagesURL[0]"></v-img>
                </div>
                <v-scale-transition>
                  <div class="selected-color" v-if="isSelected"></div>
                </v-scale-transition>
              </div>
            </v-card>
          </v-slide-group-item>
        </v-row>
      </v-slide-group>
```

this is my first post, i will try to do my best to explain and give some clues to find a solution

I tried to explain the problem to chatGPT, i try some modification, but i don't find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work when I remove the `v-row` between `v-slide-group` and `v-slide-group-item`. Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

---

[playground with centering](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: thanks for your answer, that was correct. I used v-row to make images at center of the main product card, there is an other solution by modifying "v-slide-group__content" class by adding a "justify-content : true" css property. I thinks it's more dirty but I prefer to avoid error on console

Comment: Instead of centering through `v-slide-group__content`, I would try to do it through the container. I have added another playground to the answer if it helps. Oh, and if it does, please consider leaving an upvote and/or marking it as the accepted answer. It's a bit silly, but it is how the site works...

Comment: I need 15 reputation to let a upvote ;( but thanks you so much for your help. i will accept the answer !